# mongodb php upsert if tag exist

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to update and insert a record called **'enabled'** in all entries that have a **'title'**

```
{
     "_id": ObjectId("50310c48ba76882419000001"),
     "title": "XKCD",
     "online": true
}   
{
     "_id": ObjectId("50310c48ba76882419000000"),
     "title": "Calvin and Hobbes",
     "author": "Bill Watterson"
}
```

Here is my attempt but i seem to be having some problems.
 
When i run this, nothing happens.
Any help would be appreciated

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->mydb;
$col = $db->members;

$query = array('title'=>array('$exist' => true));
$col->update($query, array('enabled' => '0' ));
```

Comment: Where do you set multi=1 ????

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem exists here:

```
$col->update($query, array('enabled' => '0' ));
```

This will actually replace all but the unmutable `_id` field with `enabled: 0`. Try the `$set` opreator:

```
$col->update($query, array('$set' => array('enabled' => '0' )), array('multiple' => true));
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set

Comment: thank you for the response. i tried that but it didnt update/insert the records

Comment: @tq Try $exists : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists instead of $exist :)

Comment: that inserted on the first item, but both items have 'title' and it skipped the second

Comment: @tq Updates are defaulted to only one, you need to add something to make it do more, let me edit a sec